# Non-Measurable Set with Measurable Slices

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{C},\nu)$ be two measure spaces. I have been asked to give an example of a set $D \in X \times Y$ such that for every $x\in X $ we have $D_x \in \mathcal{C}$ however $D \not\in \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{C}$

In words this is a set that is not measurable however every slice is measurable! In case notation is different to your studies I include that $D_x$ is defined to be the set $\{y \in Y : (x,y) \in D\}$

**My attempt**

Let us work on the Lebesgue measure and the Borel Sigma algebra on the interval $[0,1]$ that is take $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)= (Y,\mathcal{C},\nu) = (\mathbb{R}\cap[0,1] , \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}\cap[0,1]),\lambda)$

And consider the set $D := \{ (x,\mathbb{1}_{x\in V}) : x \in [0,1] \}$ Where $V$ is the Vitali set.

In essence our set is just points $(x,1)$ if $x$ is in the Vitali set or $(x,0)$ if it is not

Then clearly we have that $D_x $ is either just $\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$ both of which our measurable however It feels like $D$ should not be measurable at all. However I am stuck in showing this. I know that the slices $D^y$ are not measurable by construction for $y \in \{0,1\}$ as $D^1 = V$

I think I should go forward using Fubini that is to show that $\lambda^2(D) = \lambda \times \lambda (D) = \int_{[0,1]} D^y d\lambda(y) $ is not defined when we split $[0,1]$ into the disjoint $\{0\} , \{1\}$ and $(0,1)$

Any other examples or ways to progress with my method would be great!

Comment: So the question has nothing to do with measures $\mu,\nu$?  It is just a question on product sigma-algebras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your own example works fine. You only need to prove that $D$ is not measurable. Here is an approach: Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] \times [0,1]$ be the measurable function defined by $f(x) = (x,1)$. And consider the preimage
$$f^{-1}(D) = V.$$
Now, if $D$ was measurable, we would arrive at the conclusion that the vitali set $V$ was also measurable, which is of course false, and hence we may conclude that $D$ is not measurable.

Comment: This was so good! Thank you. I found another nice way of doing it and that is that for any measurable set $E^y$ is measurable however $E^1 =V$ is not measurable hence $E$ is not

Comment: Yes, that works as well. In fact it is somewhat equivalent to my approach, since if $f_y(x)=(x,y)$, then $f_y^{-1}(E) = E^y$ for any set $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a non-measurable set $A$ and a measurable set $B$, then $C:=A\times B$ is non-measurable in the product $\sigma $-algebra and have the property that $C_x=B$ when $x\in A$ and $C_x=\emptyset $ when $x\notin A$.

To see way $C$ is non-measurable you can take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411462/sigma-algebra-generated-by-measurable-rectangles-is-not-complete).